# Request header field Secret is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response - ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I am getting this error -

> Request header field Secret is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

On my web api in asp.net MVC.

I have enabled cors and added the headers through web.config.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" value="Key,Secret"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Now when I am trying to call this API (cross domain) in jQuery then i get error.

My jQuery Code is:

```
 var url = "http://www.demo.yogihosting.com/mvc/api/API/1"
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            headers: {
                Key: "Key1",
                Secret: "Secret1"
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                alert(result)
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error)
            }
        });
```

The API URL IS [Click HERE](http://www.demo.yogihosting.com/mvc/api/API/1)

The API needs header - 'key' & 'secret' too. 
Key value should be 'Key1'
Secret value should be 'Secret1'

The API is not working on cross domain request. But on same domain request it is working.

**Below is the image from Chrome Network tab containing Request and Response data:**
[image]

Please help me to find out what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the URL you're calling returns CORS headers in the response?

Comment: Yes they are coming, if you run the jquery code on your local pc then you can check them on chrome developer tools.

Comment: You also need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to the `customHeaders` in the web.config. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: yes i have added them on web.config.

Comment: No, you have only added `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong in web.config. It should be 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'. Now it is solved. Thank for your solving it.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working